# Redirect IP's that don't match

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site that is at a URL and I am wanting to redirect all traffic except a few IP address to a coming soon type page.

So if I had 3 IP's, those 3 IP's would see the current wordpress site and all other traffic would be redirect to a certain URL

Is this possible with Apache?   Something that could be put in an .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with  mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.255\.123\.255 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^124\.255\.124\.255 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^125\.255\.125\.255
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```